# Nashorn java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject

Tags: java, java-8, osgi, eclipse-rcp, nashorn

I am migrating my `Eclipse RCP` to use `JDK 8` and I heavily use the JS `ScriptEngine`. Now that `Nashorn` is introduced I had to add the following line to get the `importClass` and `importPackage` functions to work:

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
```

After doing so, I got **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/JSObject`**.

I am using Nashorn inside an Eclipse RCP. The problem occurs when I call a `Java` function from the `Javascript` and try to use the parameter sent. The parameter I want to send is a `Javascript` function that I would like to execute `call` on later in the code.

I have the following code:

**TestNashorn.java**

```
package com.test.nashorn;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.Invocable;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;

public class TestNashorn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngine engine = (new ScriptEngineManager()).getEngineByName("js");
        try {
            engine.eval(new FileReader("C:/Users/user/workspace_nashorn/TestNashorn/src/com/test/nashorn/test.js"));
            Object o = ((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction("generate");
        } catch (ScriptException | FileNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int test(JSObject o1) {
        System.out.println(o1.getClass().toString());
        JSObject som = ((JSObject)o1);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**test.js**

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
importClass(com.test.nashorn.TestNashorn);

function generate()
{
    function asd(variablex) { print('Hello, ' + variablex); }
    var result = TestNashorn.test(asd);
}
```

The problem occurs in line `JSObject som = ((JSObject)o1);`, although I can successfully `import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject;`.

The exception message exactly says:

> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject cannot be found by com.test.nashorn_1.0.0.qualifier

Comment: Nashorn will be deprecated in Java 11 (my last info). It might be worthy to do a bit of research and check alternatives that are not part of the JDK. E.g.: J2V8 project that embeds a V8 Javascript engine that is available on Maven Central and the JAR files contain OSGi MANIFEST headers. I have not tried it yet (it is on my task list) so if you try it and it works for you, please let me know :).

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos I don't know if adding another third party dependency to my application is the right thing to do at the moment to be honest. I will though let you know if I take the route you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So.. I got to fix my issue and was able to use `JSObject` in my code. What I have done was the following:

- Added `-Dorg.osgi.framework.bundle.parent=ext` to `myproduct.product` file

This added it to the `.ini` file in my product build which revealed the classes found in `Nashorn` APIs.